# Using R: Fama MacBeth Regression - Portfolio formation and Stock return ranking

Tags: r, loops, stata, rank, portfolio

I am very new to R (I used Stata before). I am currently re-do the some financial theory test which involves:

1. declare time series
2. calculate relevant variable like daily returns
3. rank stock performance (cross-sectional)
4. form portfolio
5. run regressions.

My questions is :

1. Should I use **wide dataset** or **long dataset** for more convenient script writing and better time-saving?
2. Which are corresponding commands I should use?

What I mean by wide dataset is having 900 columns of price for 900 stocks. Long data means 1 price column and 900 stocks in rows. This data includes daily data during last 10 years.
So this is a massive data processing. That is why any experience you share to me is precious.

**Wide data example:**

```
dateyyyymmdd          price.AAA       price.BBB
1    2015-10-02           10.1           10.7
2    2015-10-01           10.3           10.4
3    2015-09-30           10.4           10.4
4    2015-09-29           10.6           10.6
5    2015-09-28           10.7           11.0
6    2015-09-25           10.4           10.8
7    2015-09-24            9.8           10.2
8    2015-09-23            9.9           10.1
9    2015-09-22            9.9            9.9
10   2015-09-21           10.1           10.1
```

**Long data example:**

```
dateyyyymmdd             id                price
1    2015-10-02           AAA           10.7
2    2015-10-01           AAA           10.4
3    2015-09-30           AAA           10.4
4    2015-09-29           AAA           10.6
5    2015-09-28           AAA           11.0
6    2015-10-02           BBB           10.8
7    2015-10-01           BBB           10.2
8    2015-09-30           BBB           10.1
9    2015-09-29           BBB            9.9
10   2015-09-38           BBB           10.1
```

Here are my obstacles during my work:

1. declare time series and calculate daily return: I found it much harder to declare time series and use it compared to Stata. I tried `ts()` and some others but eventually I did not know how to calculate daily return for each stock in a "smart way". I tried `diff()` but it needs to apply the right order of dates.
2. ranking stock returns. I did not reach this part yet. However, if someone can help me if I should use wide or long data for time-saving purpose. I will have to rank returns accross stocks in a day then group them and calculate parameters for each group.
3. Running regression and portfolio analytics. I had a look at portfolio analytic packages and guessed that it used wide data since the given examples showed many tickers as names (1 price column for each stock) of the dataframe.

Comment: I am not a R person but this seems to me too broad and not matching good question practice here. I'd recommend expanding your #1 with specific details and a reproducible example of what code you tried with what specific problems. If you wish to engage people who know both Stata and R you still need to show Stata code if you expect a translation, in so far as that is possible. It's perhaps too obvious to state but I underline that there is no reason to expect R to provide exact syntactic equivalents to Stata any more than the opposite applies. Many of the concepts really are different.

Comment: Thank you Nick Cox, I think I will give the code I have tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To address your issues:

1. R has a number of methods for representing time series.   The `xts` package is frequently used for financial data which form an irregular time series due to missing weekends and holidays.   The `xts` package includes a version of `diff` which uses proper date ordering to calculate returns.  The code below  uses the `xts` package with `diff` on your example data to properly calculate returns.
2. The `rank` function is used to rank returns for each day.  Since `rank` only works on a single vector of data, the `apply` function is used to select each row, rank the returns, and then assemble the rankings into a matrix.    The matrix of results will need to be restored  to an `xts` time series which is done with `Reclass`.  Finally, for the purposes of the example, it might be helpful to combine data and results into one time series which is done with `merge`.
3. You indicate that you're interested in using  the `PerformanceAnalytics` package.   `xts` time series with each asset in its own column work well with the `PerformanceAnalytics`.   As an example, the code uses the calculated returns and assumes an equi-weight portfolio to calculate a time series of portfolio returns using `Return.portfolio` function from the `PerformanceAnalytics` package.

You mention that you have 10 years of daily data for 900 assets.  This number of rows is not at all large for R but the number of columns probably is.  I'd try using something like the code below and see whether there are any performance issues.  If so, there a couple of options you could try.

```
library(xts)
#   transform to an xts time series
dfx <- xts(df[,-1], order.by=as.Date(df[,1]))
#   calculate returns; no return (NA) is calculated for first date so remove
df_ret <- diff(dfx, arithmetic=FALSE, na.pad=FALSE)-1
#   label columns containing returns
colnames(df_ret) <- sub("price", "return",colnames(df_ret))
#   calculate ranks for each row of returns, add ranks as columns to data, and restore as xts time series
df_rank <- Reclass(t(apply(df_ret, 1, rank)))
#   lable columns containing ranks
colnames(df_rank) <- sub("return","rank",colnames(df_rank))
# returns and ranks can be combined with prices if desired
dfx <- merge(dfx, df_ret, df_rank)

#  Calculate returns for a portfolio equi-weighted at beginning of period and not rebalance
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
port_ret <- Return.portfolio(R=df_ret, weights=c(.5,.5))
```

Comment: Your recommendations is really helpful to me, WaltS. I am very grateful.